# Recursive Binary Search in C++

Tags: c++, list, recursion

I am trying to implement a recursive binary search. However, my function always iterates 3 times and then returns that the list I am searching through is empty. Relevant code is below. Both full() and insertAfter() work correctly.

List.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "listA.h"

using namespace std;

List::List(int a)
{
    size = a;
    actual = 0;
    data = new char[a];
    cursor = -1;
}

int List::binarySearch(List l, int value, int imin, int imax)
{
    //check if list is empty
    if(imax < imin)
    {
        //return -1 if list is empty
        return -1;
    }
     cout << "made it here" << endl;
    //calculate midpoint of set
    // problem line: int imid = imin + ((imin+imax)/2);
    int imid = (imin+imax)/2;

    //search for value
    if(l.data[imid] > value)
    {
        cout << "less than"<< endl;
        //value is in lower half
        return binarySearch(l,value,imin,imid-1);
    }

    if(l.data[imid] < value)
    {
        cout <<" greater " << endl;
        //value is in upper half
        return binarySearch(l,value,imid+1,imax);
    }
    else
    {
        //value has been found
        return imid;
    }
}

bool List::insertAfter(char c)
{
    if(!full())
    {
        if(actual >= cursor)
        {
            //shuffle values up so as to not overwrite
            for(int i=cursor+1;i<=actual;i++)
            {
                data[i]+data[i+1];

            }

        }

        //increment actual element count
        actual++;

        //add c to data after cursor
        data[cursor+1]=c;

        //increment cursor to new element
        cursor++;

        return true;

    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool List::full()const
{
    return (actual == size);
}
```

this is my listA.h

```
class List{
    public:
            List(int = 10);

int binarySearch(List l, int, int, int);
bool insertAfter(char);
bool full() const;
private:
            int size;
    int actual;
            int cursor;
            char *data;
};
```

my main.cpp is

```
int main() {
int size = 7;
char c; 
List l(size);
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if(!l.insertAfter(i + '0')) {
        cout << "inserting " << (char)(i + '0');            
        cout << "Error in insertAfter" << endl;
    }
}

cout << "TEST FOR BINARYSEARCH" << endl;
//search for 2 in the list from 0->6
cout << l.binarySearch(l,2,0,6) << endl;
}
```

My output returns
//Begin <<: 
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
end <<
TEST FOR BINARYSEARCH
made it here
less than
made it here
less than
made it here
less than
-1
//

So I am looping through three times and then returning -1, why does this happen? Where am I making my mistake in binarySearch??

Comment: You should make binarySearch static as it does not operate on the current list. Also, pass the list by const reference or you are copying it tons of times.

Comment: Please, state if this is Homework. Since you've made an attempt, I would be glad to help you.

Comment: @NeilKirk what do you mean by this?

Comment: @self _"Please, state if this is Homework."_ That's completely irrelevant!

Comment: I've removed the word "Solved" from the title. To indicate that the problem has been solved, accept an answer; feel free to post and accept an answer yourself. If you don't care to share the solution, you can delete the question.

Comment: If you have two lists, l0 and l1, what's the difference between `l0.binarySearch(l0, 2, 0, 6);` and `l1.binarySearch(l0, 2, 0, 6)`? Either don't pass a list and use the object it's called on, or make the function static.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

1. In your `binarySearch()` method, you are comparing *values*, not *keys*. This may be what you wanted but you don't have value `2` stored in your list (see point 2).
2. You `insertAfter()` method inserts `char`s that when printed give `0,1,2,3,4,5,6` but in fact their `int` values (based on which you make the comparison) are the following: `48,49,50,51,52,53,54`.

I am not sure if that's what you are trying to do here but here is a working version of the `binarySearch()` method (note the `char` to `int` conversions):

```
int List::binarySearch(List l, int value, int imin, int imax)
{
    //check if list is empty
    if(imax < imin)
    {
        //return -1 if list is empty
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "made it here" << endl;
    //calculate midpoint of set
    int imid = ((imin+imax)/2);

    //search for value
    if((int)(l.data[imid]-'0') > value) // <-- see the cast here
    {
        cout << "less than"<< endl;
        //value is in lower half
        return binarySearch(l,value,imin,imid-1);
    }

    if((int)(l.data[imid]-'0') < value) // <-- see the cast here
    {
        cout <<" greater " << endl;
        //value is in upper half
        return binarySearch(l,value,imid+1,imax);
    }
    if((int)(l.data[imid]-'0') == value) // <-- see the cast here (this part of your program could be simplified by removing this condition and leaving only the return)
    {
        //value has been found
        return l.data[imid];  // <-- see the modified return here
    }
}
```

And here is the code for creating the list:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  cout << "inserting " << (int)(i + '0');
    if(!l.insertAfter(i + '0')) { // <-- note the conversion from int to char 
        cout << "Error in insertAfter" << endl;
    }
}
```

I think you can go from here and modify your code appropriately.